# binary responses with Serverless, Bref PHP, and Slim getting CORS or base64 encoded

Tags: serverless, bref

I have been setting up a [Serverless(.com)](https://serverless.com) setup with AWS, using [Bref (PHP layer)](https://bref.sh) to run [MPDF](https://mpdf.github.io/) to convert HTML to PDF using AWS Lambda and API Gateway. Following instructions,.. here is the setup.

After way to much debugging, it appears that either I can:

1. Add the `apiGateway` option in the serverless file, but I **always** get a CORS issue (i.e. the classic `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present`). I have tried every combination of headers from the client/request side and responses from the server side (see code below).
2. OR, I can not have the `apiGateway` option, as below, but then I **have** to base64encode my body (see `$body = base64_encode($pdf);`) or I get a Bref error stating `The Lambda response cannot be encoded to JSON (...)`  saying one should use the `apiGateway` options.

Encoding the body is fine, but doesn't work well for direct download as I need to base64decode the `data` from the response in order to have the binary data.

Help.

**serverless.yml**:  (notice the commented out apiGateway settings - read more for why)

```
 service: html2pdf
    
    provider:
        name: aws
        region: us-east-1
        runtime: provided
        stage: ${opt:stage, 'dev'}
        # apiGateway:    ## <======= We talk about this below
        #     binaryMediaTypes:
        #         - '*/*'
        # environment:
        #     BREF_BINARY_RESPONSES: 1
    
    plugins:
        - ./vendor/bref/bref
    
    functions:
        html2pdf:
            handler: index.php
            description: ''
            timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
            layers:
                - ${bref:layer.php-73-fpm} #-fpm
            events:
                - http:
                    path: /html2pdf
                    method: post
                    cors: true
    
       
    
    # Exclude files from deployment
    package:
        exclude:
            - 'node_modules/**'
            - 'tests/**'
```

The **index.php** (mentioned in the yml file above):

```
 <?php
    
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
    
    use App\JsonParserMiddleware;
    
    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
    
    $app = AppFactory::create();
    $app->addMiddleware(new JsonParserMiddleware());
    
    $app->post("/html2pdf", function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        
        $data = $request->getParsedBody();
        $payload = [];
        $statusCode = 200;
        if ($data['data'] == null) {
            $payload['error'] = "HTML 64-bit encoded string is required";
            return response($response, $payload, 422);
        }
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['tempDir' => '/tmp']);
        $mpdf->WriteHTML(base64_decode($data['data']));
        
        $pdf = $mpdf->Output(null,"S");
    
        $filename = $data['title'];
    
        $body = base64_encode($pdf);
    
        $response->getBody()->write($body);
    
        $response->isBase64Encoded = true;
        
        $response = $response 
                    ->withHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                    ->withHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', "true")  
                    ->withHeader('Content-Type','application/pdf')
                    ->withHeader('Content-Disposition', sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $filename))
                    ->withStatus($statusCode);
        
        return $response;
        
    });
```

And the client-side code, using axios, is:

```
let data = { data: <<some base64 encoded html string>>, title: "file.pdf" };

let options = {
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                // "Accept": "*/*",
              },
             }
let payload = {data : btoa(data),title:"contract.pdf"};
let url = "https://oli9w0wghb.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/html2pdf";

axios.post(url, payload, options)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same problem, and I fixed it:

The headers i used in the controller are (Im using SLIM4):

```
    $response->getBody()->write($pdfContent);
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
    $response->isBase64Encoded = true;
```

Then to configure the serverless.yml i need to add:

```
service: *****

provider:
    region: ****
    runtime: ***
    profile: ****
    apiGateway:
        binaryMediaTypes:
            - 'application/pdf'
    environment:
        BREF_BINARY_RESPONSES: '1'
       


plugins:
    - ./vendor/bref/bref

functions:
    api:
        handler: public/index.php
        description: ''
        timeout: 28 # in seconds (API Gateway has a timeout of 29 seconds)
        layers:
            - ${bref:layer.php-81-fpm}
        events:
            -   http: ANY /{proxy+}
        environment:
            BREF_BINARY_RESPONSE: '1'
```

I hope this helps you.